# Magit: patches that ignore some whitespace changes do not apply

Tags: magit, git

*Context*: I'm doing a merge, and fixed the conflicts manually. Now I'm trying to stage changes hunk-by-hunk and make a commit.

*Issue*: some hunks are not getting staged.

Here's the output from `magit-process` buffer

> git … apply --cached -p0 --ignore-space-change -
>
> error: patch failed: filename.cpp:1302
>
> error: filename.cpp: patch does not apply

I was wondering what can be done to fix or investigate the issue. This is happening on Spacemacs on Fedora.

---

With some experimentation, I've found that this issue only happens when the flag `--ignore-all-space` is set, i.e., if I unset this, then I can stage the same hunk.

edit: This could be a possible bug since I could reproduce it on a smaller issue. I've made a bug-report [here](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3608)

Comment: Does the hunk in question have non-space differences?

Comment: @WillyLee. The hunk in question does have non-space differences. I'll try to see if I can form a minimal example. I suspect this could be a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magit now automatically uses `git apply -C0 ...` when appropriate. That causes the context lines to be ignored and as a result patches that ignore some whitespace changes apply again.

2.92.0 will be the first release to support this.